# Count rows with value 1 based on date row reference

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to get a formula to work to count the number of **consuctive** 1's equal to or less than today's row reference.

E.g. 
Date

```
1/19/2020     1
1/20/2020     0
1/21/2020     1
1/22/2020     1
1/23/2020     1
1/24/2020     1
```

The result should be 4. The counted range should be 1/24/2020 - 1/21/2020

I am able to get the row index of today's date with: `=(MATCH(TODAY(),A:A,0))`
and I was trying to use the following formula
`{=ROW(A12) - MAX(--($A$1:A11=A12)*ROW($A$1:A11))}`
However I cannot get this to be dynamic based on today's index.

Would appreciate any tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data sits in `A1:B6`.

Somewhat long (But I wanted to avoid whole range references):

```
=MATCH(TODAY(),A:A,0)-LOOKUP(2,1/(B1:INDEX(B:B,MATCH(TODAY(),A:A,0))=0),ROW(B1:INDEX(B:B,MATCH(TODAY(),A:A,0))))
```

If no single `0` in your range, then apply an `IFERROR` and use a `MATCH` on its own.